# Raspberry Pi RasPiComm

Tags: hardware, setup

I am wondering about how the Raspberry Pi RasPiComm works. I am thinking of buying one from: http://raspberrypi.rsdelivers.com/default.aspx?cl=1

I am actually wondering how it works?

What do you need to make it work?

Any software I need for it?
 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RasPiComm FAQ](http://www.amescon.com/products/faq.aspx) answers all your questions and could be easily found by googling for "RasPiComm". Even more info could be found in [RasPiComm technical specs](http://www.amescon.com/products/technical-specifications.aspx).

Well, for people who cannot read FAQ, here's a short quote:

```
Q: What is the RasPiComm?
A: It is a piggyback extension board for the RaspberryPi.
```

Basically, it's a board you connect to the RaspberryPi to get some extra functionality, like communucation ports, LEDs, HW clock and more (read [RasPiComm technical specs](http://www.amescon.com/products/technical-specifications.aspx) for details).

**What do you need to use it?** -- well, you need RaspberryPi with power supply and SD card to boot from and, basically, RasPiComm itself. Or maybe you don't need RasPiComm -- I don't know, that depends on what's your purpose -- probably you need a completely different setup altogether.

**What do you need to make it work?** -- connect all connectors, insert SD card, attach power and see what happens. If there's no smoke -- it works, if there's a smoke -- disconnect the power and try to find the cause. Please, don't inhale, may be hazardous for your health.

**Any software you need for it?** -- obviously, the browser, preferably Mozilla or Chrome, to read the plethora of online pages with the information pertaining to RaspberryPi and RasPiComm.

Comment: Still not answering all of my questions

Comment: Considering I am a beginner.

Comment: Comments do allow HTML links.  Do do one, put it in the form of [text](html link).

Comment: @syb0rg well, let's try: [RasPiComm FAQ](http://www.amescon.com/products/faq.aspx) -- that works, thank you! =)

Comment: This was the only thing that helped me... Basically, it's a board you connect to the RaspberryPi to get some extra functionality, like communucation ports, LEDs, HW clock and more. The rest is just sarcastic garbage

Comment: @loko are you somehow related to the RasPiComm project and trying to advertize it on this site by asking related questions?

Comment: @lenik what? no nvm